# Specific call working with curl but not with Wget

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, wget

Hi we have an issue where

`curl --cacert <cacert Path>  --cert <client cert.pem path> --key <keypath>  https://samplesite.com`

The above general  command is not working but when **we try pointing the --capath to the same client certificate it is working fine** like the url below.

`curl --cacert <cacert Path>  --cert < client certificate cert.pem path> --key <keypath>  --capath <client cert.pem path directory> https://samplesite.com`

Now when we try the same with the wget we were getting the SSL handshake exception

`wget  https://samplesite.com --certificate=< client certificate cert.pem path>     --private-key=<keypath> rps_masterinstaller/keys/rps_masterinstaller-key.pem --ca-certificate=<cacert Path>   --ca-directory=< client certificate cert.pem path directory>`

We need to make it work for the wget need some help in debugging this. Some mentioned that as it is an intermediate certificate, in the curl

because they are both documented for peer verification on the client side, **but it appears capath certs are also being sent to the TLS server as part of the client cert chain**

Comment: I think issue is with "--ca-directory=< client certificate cert.pem path directory>" , Because it should point to the directory where we have CA Cert not 'client cert' and also when you are using "--ca-certificate=<cacert Path>" why to use "--ca-directory" again .

Comment: Hi , we tested it in the CURL and pointing to the ** client cert ** path is working as some how ** it appears capath certs are also being sent to the TLS server as part of the client cert chain **